# python encoding utf-8

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am doing some scripts in python. I create a string that I save in a file. This string got lot of data, coming from the arborescence and filenames of a directory.
According to convmv, all my arborescence is in UTF-8.

I want to keep everything in UTF-8 because I will save it in MySQL after.
For now, in MySQL, which is in UTF-8, I got some problem with some characters (like é or è - I'am French).

I want that python always use string as UTF-8. I read some informations on the internet and i did like this.

My script begin with this :

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 def createIndex():
     import codecs
     toUtf8=codecs.getencoder('UTF8')
     #lot of operations & building indexSTR the string who matter
     findex=open('config/index/music_vibration_'+date+'.index','a')
     findex.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)
     findex.write(toUtf8(indexSTR)) #this bugs!
```

And when I execute, here is the answer : `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2171: ordinal not in range(128)`

Edit:
I see, in my file, the accent are nicely written. After creating this file, I read it and I write it into MySQL.
But I dont understand why, but I got problem with encoding.
My MySQL database is in utf8, or seems to be SQL query `SHOW variables LIKE 'char%'` returns me only utf8 or binary.

My function looks like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def saveIndex(index,date):
    import MySQLdb as mdb
    import codecs

    sql = mdb.connect('localhost','admin','*******','music_vibration')
    sql.charset="utf8"
    findex=open('config/index/'+index,'r')
    lines=findex.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.find('#artiste') != -1:
            artiste=line.split('[:::]')
            artiste=artiste[1].replace('\n','')

            c=sql.cursor()
            c.execute('SELECT COUNT(id) AS nbr FROM artistes WHERE nom="'+artiste+'"')
            nbr=c.fetchone()
            if nbr[0]==0:
                c=sql.cursor()
                iArt+=1
                c.execute('INSERT INTO artistes(nom,status,path) VALUES("'+artiste+'",99,"'+artiste+'/")'.encode('utf8')
```

And artiste who are nicely displayed in the file writes bad into the BDD.
What is the problem ?

Comment: Your python sample code is invalid; there are syntax errors in at least 2 places. Can you fix those first, please?

Comment: Are you saving the file as utf-8 and not an ascii file?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You don't need to encode data that is *already* encoded. When you try to do that, Python will first try to *decode* it to `unicode` before it can encode it back to UTF-8. That is what is failing here:

```
>>> data = u'\u00c3'            # Unicode data
>>> data = data.encode('utf8')  # encoded to UTF-8
>>> data
'\xc3\x83'
>>> data.encode('utf8')         # Try to *re*-encode it
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Just write your data directly to the file, there is *no* need to encode already-encoded data.

If you instead build up `unicode` values instead, you would indeed have to encode those to be writable to a file. You'd want to use [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) instead, which returns a file object that will encode unicode values to UTF-8 for you.

You also *really* don't want to write out the UTF-8 BOM, *unless* you *have* to support Microsoft tools that cannot read UTF-8 otherwise (such as MS Notepad).

For your MySQL insert problem, you need to do two things:

- Add `charset='utf8'` to your `MySQLdb.connect()` call.
- Use `unicode` objects, not `str` objects when querying or inserting, but *use sql parameters* so the MySQL connector can do the right thing for you:

  ```
  artiste = artiste.decode('utf8')  # it is already UTF8, decode to unicode

  c.execute('SELECT COUNT(id) AS nbr FROM artistes WHERE nom=%s', (artiste,))

  # ...

  c.execute('INSERT INTO artistes(nom,status,path) VALUES(%s, 99, %s)', (artiste, artiste + u'/'))
  ```

It may actually work better if you used `codecs.open()` to decode the contents automatically instead:

```
import codecs

sql = mdb.connect('localhost','admin','ugo&(-@F','music_vibration', charset='utf8')

with codecs.open('config/index/'+index, 'r', 'utf8') as findex:
    for line in findex:
        if u'#artiste' not in line:
            continue

        artiste=line.split(u'[:::]')[1].strip()

    cursor = sql.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(id) AS nbr FROM artistes WHERE nom=%s', (artiste,))
    if not cursor.fetchone()[0]:
        cursor = sql.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO artistes(nom,status,path) VALUES(%s, 99, %s)', (artiste, artiste + u'/'))
        artists_inserted += 1
```

You may want to brush up on Unicode and UTF-8 and encodings. I can recommend the following articles:

- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky

Comment: @vekah: Did you follow the instructions in [Writing UTF-8 String to MySQL with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6202726)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the string.encode() method is not always reliable. Check out this thread for more information: [What is the fool proof way to convert some string (utf-8 or else) to a simple ASCII string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792602/what-is-the-fool-proof-way-to-convert-some-string-utf-8-or-else-to-a-simple-as)