# Python unittest.mock library

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I'm writing unit tests for a requests library. For most of my libraries, I run a `.content.decode('utf-8')` on the response to get to the actual text. However when I'm mocking this response from the api call, how do I mock a response object which is received by the requests call? is there a `requests.content.encode('utf-8',data))` look alike process which can actually mock the response coming in (in encoded format) from the API call, and then I decode that object.

sample code:

```
def sample_fct(self, endpoint):
    try:
        request = requests.post (endpoint, verify=False)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise
    return request

def get_something(self,test):
    try:
        response = self.sample_fct(test)
        resp_text = response_bare.content.decode('utf-8')
        print resp_text
    except:
        raise
```

So for instance, if I wanted to unit test the `get_something` function, I need to mock the `sample_fct` function. to do this, i would have to set the `sample_fct.return_value` to a request object that it is returning.

So how do I create that object.

Comment: Have you check the packages [requests-mock](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? It is very useful when mocking `requests` calls.

Comment: Can we see an example of your current mocking? I can write up a better example of how it should look if I have a starting point. Essentially you'd just assign the response (or a portion of a mocked response) to an already encoded value. You can either do that with raw bytes like this: `b'\xE2\x98\xBA'` or by starting with the encoded string and call `encode` like this: `'☺'.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: What should `requests.content.encode('utf-8',data))` do?

Comment: @wholevinski added a sample

Comment: You can assign arbitrary attributes to a `Mock`, so it'd be something like: `mock_fct_return = mock.Mock(content=b'some content you want to decode')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can mock the response like I was saying above. Note that I took some liberties to make your code and my test actually work. They are included in comments:

```
"""request_module.py"""
import requests


class SomeClass(object):
    """I put these in a class, since you had self as your first arg"""
    def sample_fct(self, endpoint):
        try:
            request = requests.post (endpoint, verify=False)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            raise
        return request

    def get_something(self, test):
        try:
            response = self.sample_fct(test)
            resp_text = response.content.decode('utf-8')
            # Changed to return the value instead of print it
            return resp_text
        except:
            raise
```

You can see in the test how I assign the return value of your mocked `sample_fct` to an arbitrary `Mock` object. That object can have arbitrary attributes assigned to it, which can aid in testing for return values that may be many attribute levels deep.

```
"""test_request_module.py"""
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock

from request_module import SomeClass

class TestRequests(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('request_module.SomeClass.sample_fct')
    def test_get_something(self, mock_sample_fct):
        mock_sample_fct.return_value = mock.Mock(content=b'some content you want to decode \xE2\x98\xBA')
        # Testing that your decoded value is returned
        some_class = SomeClass()
        result = some_class.get_something('some_test_value')
        # Note the decoded smiley face
        self.assertEqual('some content you want to decode ☺', result)
```

Note that you can also assign attributes of attributes on a `Mock`. So if your caller is expecting something like `request.attributes.nested_attributes.value`, you could do something like this and `Mock` will allow it:

```
mock_ret = mock.Mock()
mock_ret.request.attributes.nested_attributes.value = 'deep attr value'
```

Comment: Just a follow up question.. the `.content.decode`, which library is that from? I thought it was from the requests library.. but it turns out it isn't? (I didnt import requests, and was still able to use `content.decode`

Comment: `.content` is an attribute on the response object coming back from the `requests` library. `.decode` is a function on strings. `.content` is in raw byte form, so using `decode` will take those bytes and turn them back into the intended representation (perhaps a UTF8 smiley face like above). Whenever you see a `u` before a string in python 2.7, that's a unicode string; the default strings in python 3 are already unicode. I could go on for awhile about this; I'd recommend checking out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092437/python-encoding-utf-8